# Gmail API to send an inline images

Tags: gmail-api

How can i send an inline images using Google API, here is my sameple code
Kindy let me know what am i missing ?

```
String email =
                    "Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary:\"multipart_related_boundary\"\r\n" +
                                    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" +
                                    FROM_ME +
                                    TO + toAddress + "\r\n" +
                                    SUBJECT + "welcome" + "\r\n"
                                    + "--multipart_related_boundary" + "\r\n" +
                                    "Content-type: image/gif; name=\"083.gif\"\r\n" +
                                    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" +
                                    "Content-ID: <083.gif>\r\n" +
                                    "Content-Disposition: inline\r\n"
                                    + "--multipart_related_boundary" + "\r\n" +
                                    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" +
                                    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n" +
                                    CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING_QUOTED_PRINTABLE +
                                    "<html><body><img src=\"cid:083.gif\"/> welcome " +
                                    "</body></html>\r\n\r\n";

    byte[] converted = Base64.encodeBase64(email.getBytes());

    String encodedStr = new String(converted);
    encodedStr = encodedStr.replace("/", "_").replace("+", "-");

    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse(APPLICATION_JSON);
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, RAW + encodedStr + END_BRACKET);

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(HTTPS_WWW_GOOGLEAPIS_COM_GMAIL_V1_USERS_ME_MESSAGES_SEND).post(body)
                    .addHeader(AUTHORIZATION,
                                    BEARER + gmailAuthService.getRefreshToken(token).getAccessToken())
                    .addHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, "multipart/related; boundary:\"multipart_related_boundary\"").build();

    Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
```

Finally in my gmail, i am not able to seethe inline image.

Answer (score 1):

You are including the image section of your MIME message, but not the image itself.

After the `Content-ID: <083.gif>` and `Content-Disposition: inline headers` you need to include the actual image.  Specifically, you probably want to add a `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` header to that section and include a base64 encoded image payload.

An easy way to see how it could/should work is to use Gmail to email yourself a short test email with a small image.  Then, in Gmail (Web UI) go to the message options (near the Reply button) and select "Show Original".  That will show you exactly how the MIME message is built.